# I want to rename xml element "product" to "Item" without changing its attributes,but i don't know how to do that

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

Input XML:

```
<ProductList>
    <Product Action="Manage" ProductID="Item_1">
        <PrimaryInformation Description="Item 1"
            Status="3000" ShortDescription="Item 1" />
    </Product>
    <Product Action="Manage" ProductID="Item_2">
        <PrimaryInformation Description="Item 2"
            Status="3000" ShortDescription="Item 2" />
    </Product>
    <Product Action="Manage" ProductID="Item_3">
        <PrimaryInformation Description="Item 3"
            Status="3000" ShortDescription="Item 3" />
    </Product>
</ProductList>
```

Expected XML Output :

```
<ProductList >
  <Item Action="Manage" ProductID="Item_1" >
   <PrimaryInformation Description="Item 1" Status="3000" ShortDescription="Item 1" /> 
 </Item> 
 <Item Action="Manage" ProductID="Item_2" >
   <PrimaryInformation Description="Item 2" Status="3000" ShortDescription="Item 2" /> 
 </Item>
  <Item Action="Manage" ProductID="Item_3" > 
  <PrimaryInformation Description="Item 3" Status="3000" ShortDescription="Item 3" />
  </Item>
 </ProductList>
```

I tried this XML template it's working but it also removes all attributes present in that element.

```
<xsl:template match="Product">
    <xsl:element name="Item">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following XSLT.

It follows the **Identity Transform** pattern.

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Product">
      <Item >
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </Item >
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```